# Submit button gets freezed after submitting the form via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

When I submit form using jQuery-Ajax in ROR the submit button gets freezed.
I am practicing ["Integrating Ajax and Rails: A Simple Todo List App"](http://roseweixel.github.io/blog/2015/07/05/integrating-ajax-and-rails-a-simple-todo-list-app/), provided by GitHub.

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
    def create
        #binding.pry
        @todo = Todo.create(todo_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to home_path}
            format.js {}
        end
    end

    private

    def todo_params
        params.require(:todo).permit(:description, :priority)
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h2>Create Todos</h2>
<%= render 'new' %>

<h2>Todos List</h2>
<ul>
    <%= render @todos %>
</ul>
```

_new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for Todo.new, html: {id: "form1"} do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :priority %>
    <%= f.text_field :priority %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

_todo.html.erb

```
<li>
    <%= todo.description %><br>
    <strong>Priority:</strong><%= todo.priority %><br>
    <%= link_to 'done', todo_path(todo) , method: 'delete' %>
</li>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("ul").append("<%= j render partial: 'todo', locals: {todo: @todo} %>");
```

app/assets/javascript/todos.js

```
$(function(){
    $("#form1").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let method = $(this).attr('method');
    let action = $(this).attr('action');
    let description = $(this).find('#todo_description').val();
    let priority = $(this).find('#todo_priority').val();
    let data = $(this).serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        method: method,
        url: action,
        data: data,

        dataType: 'script'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Quick side note: you should use `destroy` instead of `delete`. `delete` skips callbacks, which you don’t want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button gets frozen because nowadays there is a jquery script that disables it to prevent multiple submissions. Check for any classes/attributes added to the submit button when it's clicked, and then put some jquery to your create.js.erb to remove them and also clear the fields if you want to submit a new todo item.